# How to insert data into Sqlite Database using Loop?

Tags: android, netbeans, android-sqlite

Here is my short code i am inserting 10 rows into table but after complete loop 
why i have same visualisation like  "0  Net  0" ten time ?
//Table Structure

```
 String creater = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS est (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,codigo VARCHAR(10),"
    + "produto VARCHAR(1000), "
    + "qtd VARCHAR(10) ) ";
    sql.execSQL(creater);
```

//Loop of Insertion

```
   for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues(); 
    values.put("codigo", String.valueOf(i));
    values.put("produto", "Net");
    values.put("qtd", String.valueOf(i));
    sql.insert("est", null, values);
    }
```

//ArrayList

```
public  ArrayList<String>  estoque(SQLiteDatabase sql)
     {
    ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
    String cmd ="select * from est";
    Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(cmd,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int i=0;
    while(c.getCount() > i )
    {
    lst.add(c.getString(1)+"|"+c.getString(2)+"|"+c.getString(3));
    i++;
    }
    }catch(Exception ex){Log.e("ERROR", ex.getStackTrace().toString());}
    return lst;
    };
```

//ListView

```
 ListView  listview =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
ArrayList<String> estoque = new db().estoque(sql);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, estoque);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
listview.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

//visualisation
`"0 Net 0"` 10 time same. is there somthing wrong please help?

Comment: Where do you visualize the data?

Comment: String cmd ="select * from est";
Cursor c = sql.rawQuery(cmd,null);
c.moveToFirst();
int i=0;
while(c.getCount() > i )
{
lst.add(c.getString(1)+"|"+c.getString(2)+"|"+c.getString(3));
i++;
} // i am getting all records like this code

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information. It's hard to read a lot of code in a comment.

Comment: check now where i have problem?

Comment: Read my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop where you read from the database (either before or after you increase the `i` variable), you should call `c.moveToNext();`. Otherwise you are reading from the same row over and over again.

[The documentation states:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext%28%29)

```
public abstract boolean moveToNext ()
Move the cursor to the next row.
This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set.

Returns
    whether the move succeeded.
```